# Is there a way to do an SQL update statement that updates based on the content of the cell

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm playing around with MySQL running in Ubuntu. I have sample data in the table `property`. There are names in the column `name` that are strings including quotes around them. In order to select them, I have to run something like this:

```
select * from property
where name = '"john"'
```

The results show `"john"`

Is there an easy way to remove all the quotes from all the names?

Is there a way to delete the third character in each string in a column?

Is it possible to replace each instance of a character within a column with another character?

For example, if names James, Jane, and Jeffrey were in the column, replacing e's with o's would produce Jamos, Jano, and Joffroy.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if it's homework?

Comment: @Quassnoi Its not homework. I'm on break between quarters right now actually. There is no rush. You can wait a few weeks to answer to ensure a late assignment if you are worried about this being homework.

Comment: it's OK, it's just considered a good tone to tag homework as `homework`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update property
set name = replace(name,'"','');

update property
set name = replace(name,SUBSTRING ( name , 3 ,1),'');

update property
set name = replace(name,'a','o');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. They unfortunately didn't work for me. I get this error: '1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1'

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what made it work the second time around. I must have had a typo.